# Add class in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="parent"> <input type="text" /> </div>

$('.parent > *')
    .focus(function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
```

I'm trying to add a class in a div only if the input field has value. 
I mean if we put text in input field the div automatically should add a class it's self. Bu the only problem is we can't give any class name or Id
to input.

Using this script about we can add class when we click on input. But we need to do more.

Can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input` instead of `focus`. You also have to check the value to add/remove the class. Try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.parent > *').focus();
  $('.parent > *')
    .on('input', function() {
      if($(this).val().trim() != '')
        $(this).parent().addClass('focused');
      else
        $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
    });
});
```

```css
.focused{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">Test <input type="text" /> </div>
```

Comment: This is working good. The only problem is when we refresh the class is removing but the value is still there. Can we do something for that. That is the logic right? I'm just asking if I'm wrong please correct me. Thanks :)

Comment: You are almost there. Can you please help?

Comment: @Coder95, according to my logic, on page refresh the value as well as the class should not be there...

Comment: Is there any way to make that class there?

Comment: @Coder95, but if there is no value in the input initially why do you want the class to be added in the element?

Comment: No i'm not saying that. The two situations are. (1) When we refresh the page the value still be there. (2) When we click submit button and if the values are wrong, it will show error message. I mean the values also will be there. So in these two situations the class also have to be there

Comment: @Coder95, do you have the code for retaining the value on page refresh? As this is another issue, to accomplish that you might need *localStorage* or *sessionStorage*.....

Answer (score 0):

With the html you provided, this should work

```
$('.parent > *')
.focus(function() {
   if( $(this).val().length) $(this).parent().addClass('focused');
})
.blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val().length) $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
});
```

Update after OP comment

```
<div class="some-div">Hello</div>
<div class="parent"> <input type="text" /> </div>

$('.parent > *')
.focus(function() {
    $(".some-div").addClass('focused');
})
.blur(function() {
    $('.some-div').removeClass('focused');
});
```

Comment: This is working fine. But when we put value in input the generated class adding in input. We need to add class in another outer div. Can we edit this?

Comment: Yes, give the correct selector and it should work `$('SELECTOR').addClass('focused');`

Comment: This works, there is minor issue with the logic. When the input has value the div add a new class its self.

Comment: Yes, the div will be added the class `focused` . How do you want to have it?

Comment: When we type something in input the div should generate a new class. Also suppose we are refreshing the page ( not hard refresh ) the value still be there in input then also generated class should be there in div.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use `.parent > input`:

```
$('.parent > input')
    .focus(function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
```

Comment: This is working fine. But when we put value in input the generated class adding in input. We need to add class in another outer div. Can we edit this?

Comment: Another outer div?

Comment: Yeah, suppose the input is inside three divs. So we able to generate new class for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here `input` event fires on Keyboard input, Mouse Drag, Autofill, and Copy-Paste.

You can try below code -

```js
function toggleParentClass(elem) {
  console.log(elem.val());
  if (elem.val().length)
    elem.closest('.parent').addClass('focused');
  else
    elem.closest('.parent').removeClass('focused');
}

$('.parent').on('input', function() {
  toggleParentClass($(this).find('input'));
});
```

```css
.focused {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: What if you drag and drop text into the input field? Or paste by right-click with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a event-listener on the input field.

If the input box goes empty, remove the class. Otherwise, add the required class.

[Closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) helps you find the closest member with the given selection criteria.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('input').change(function(){
     if( $(this).val().trim() === '' ){//Empty input box
        $(this).closest('.parent').removeClass('focused');
     }
     else{
        $(this).closest('.parent').addClass('focused');
     }
  }
);
```

Comment: But sir, when we refresh the page ( not hard refresh ) the value is there but class is not there. Our logic is whenever the input has values the div should add class it's slef.

Comment: The two situations are. (1) When we refresh the page the value still be there.  (2) When we click submit button and if the values are wrong, it will show error message. I mean the values also will be there. So in these two situations the class also have to be there.

Comment: This seems like a different question altogether. Would you be handling the input value retention?